# Calculate x & y position from centerpoint in circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am aware that this question have been asked before, and I checked a lot of posts and I realize my math is not good enough to solve this problem.

I have a circle, which is the centerpoint at x = 0.0 & y = 0.0. Based on degree, 270 in this example, I want to place the x-box on x & y at the specified degree from the centerpoint. I just cannot get it right, not even with the examples I have found. Below is the current code I test as well as the result of 270 degree test, x-box is positioned wrongly as it is not 270 degree angle.

I would appreciate any help.

[image]

```js
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class testscript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Image im1, im2;
    public Text im1txt, im2txt, deg;
    private float degree = 270f; 
    private float x, y;


    void Start()
    {
        im1.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
        im1txt.text = im1.rectTransform.anchoredPosition.ToString();


        deg.text = degree + " degrees";

        x = 0f + (100 * Mathf.Cos(degree * Mathf.PI / 360f));
        y = 0f + (100 * Mathf.Sin(degree * Mathf.PI / 360f));


        im2.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
        im2txt.text = im2.rectTransform.anchoredPosition.ToString();


    }


}

I have tested the two suggestions below and basically get the same result as all the others. Let me visualize the result I get with the last test I done:

const float deg_to_rad = 2f * Mathf.PI / 360f;
    var radians = degree * deg_to_rad;
    x = 0 + Mathf.Cos(radians) * 100;
    y = 0 + Mathf.Sin(radians) * 100;

Here is the result:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Solution is, Sin and Cos was swapped. Thanks J.Lengel:

float x = 1f + (100 * Mathf.Sin(angelDegree * Mathf.PI / 180));
float y = -14f + (100 * Mathf.Cos(angelDegree * Mathf.PI / 180));
```

Comment: Is your example showing where you want the box or where the box is placed based on your code?

Comment: this is the code currently place the x-box when using 270 degree in my code, wrong spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Math.cos and Math.sin you are converting from degrees to radians by dividing by 360. This will not work as 360 degrees is the equivalent of 2pi in radians as opposed to pi. This means you have to divide by 180, or multiply degrees by 2. Hope that helps!

I've noticed that you take the cosine for x and the sin for y. Swap this; you want to go clockwise and the way you're doing it is for going counterclockwise.

```
x = x_origin + Math.sin(angle) * radius;
y = y_origin + Math.cos(angle) * radius;
```

Answer (score 0):

A full circle (360 degrees) is 2*PI radians:

```
x = 0f + (100 * Mathf.Cos(degree * 2 * Mathf.PI / 360f));
y = 0f + (100 * Mathf.Sin(degree * 2 * Mathf.PI / 360f));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const float deg_to_rad = 2f * Mathf.PI / 360f
var radians = degrees * deg_to_rad;
x = x_orig + Mathf.Cos(radians) * radius;
y = y_orig + Mathf.Sin(radians) * radius;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to add this to the original post but could not so I post here.

I have tested the above and get the same results as I have gotten with the majority of my previous tests. It seems to work on like 45 & 225 degree but not the 90, 180 & 270.

It is probably my math competence that fails and I guess it is a simple problem to solve.

The last test I did, with is represented in. the picture is:

```
const float deg_to_rad = 2f * Mathf.PI / 360f;
var radians = degree * deg_to_rad;
x = 0 + Mathf.Cos(radians) * 100;
y = 0 + Mathf.Sin(radians) * 100;
im2.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
```

Here is the latest results from my tests with the above code:

[image]

Comment: im2.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);                                           >> to move the x-box (text)

Comment: Absolutely stupid mistake solved by @J. Lengel I had swapped the Sin and Cos, which caused the problem.